# Select a custom python environment/version in pex file

Tags: python, pex

in my environment I have `python 3.8.5` and `pex 2.1.20`
I'm bundling some libraries in a pex file with this command:

```
pex module1 module2 module3 -o custom_env.pex
```

The reason being that I want to transfer this pex file on another machine and then run a Python script with the command `./custom_env.pex python_script.py` in order to provide it all the required dependencies.

The problem is that pex is currently using `/usr/bin/env python3.8` while on that machine `python 2.6.6` is running. Therefore when I run the pex file I receive the error

```
/usr/bin/env: python3.8: No such file or directory
```

How can I build the pex file so that it matches the destination python environment?

Comment: I am not familiar with pex, but a word of caution: python 2.6 and python 3.8 are not compatible. You will run into problems if you try to execute some code written fro python3.8 with python2.6. If you can install python3 on the target machine, I would recommend it.

Comment: Good point. In fact I prefer to work with python3. However, changing interpreter on the target machine is not feasible at the moment :(

Comment: I have the same problem, where I build pex with 3.8 and at destination i have 3.6. And I am getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

The comments to the above question have already warned about the incompatibility between Python 2 and Python 3.

The interpreter compatibility of the resulting PEX file can be controlled using the `--python` option of the `pex` command (see [Invoking the PEX utility](https://pex.readthedocs.io/en/v2.1.42/buildingpex.html#invoking-the-pex-utility)). For example, the command `pex --python=python3.6 -o py36.pex` will create a PEX file that can be run using Python 3.6. The Shebang of the result PEX file will be `#!/usr/bin/env python3.6`.

PEX is also capable of supporting multiple Python versions or even multiple platforms in a single PEX executable. You can achieve this by specifying the `--python` or `--platform` options to the PEX command multiple times with different values.

Note that PEX is using Pip to resolve the dependencies. When specifying the `--python` or `--platform` options, Pip requires that all your dependencies are available as binary wheels for the target platform and Python version. If any of the dependency is only available as a source tarball, Pip's dependency resolution will fail.